# Just installed 14.04 LTS, all apt-get attempts fail, why?

Tags: networking, apt, proxy

just installed 14.04 LTS from a usb-flash drive I built using the downloaded .iso image and a tool from pendrivelinux.com.
I booted the PC off of the usb-drive, and the installation appeared to go well, but I've been unsuccessful with `apt-get <package>`. When I run `apt-get update`, it gives messages that imply there is no network connection; however, I am able to use Firefox and browse the web.

The output of `apt-get update` hangs at:

```
0% [Connecting to mirror.cc.columbia.edu (128.59.59.71)] [Connecting to archive
```

Eventually more error messages come out (http://www.umonfw.com/tmp/update_log) all of which imply an inability to connect to the network.  Messages say "failed to fetch... unable to connect to -server-name-here--".

I tried changing the **Download From** entry in **Software & Updates**->**Ubuntu Software**, but that hangs while `querying software sources` and the details say `network isn't available`.  But while its telling me that I'm able to open a firefox window and browse the web.

I think that tells me I have networking and my http proxy set correctly, so any idea what I may be doing wrong?

One point to note, this machine is low on RAM, so while it is a 64bit AMD, I installed the 32-bit version because there was implication at the install page that this was the choice to go with for systems with less than 2G of ram.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Uhm. Always install 64bit, unless you can't. Your processor supports it, so please install that.

Comment: Post the exact command you ran and error message. Most common problem is when you are using a proxy server .

Comment: In Update Manager try changing the server where updates are fetched.

Comment: @Whaaaat.. I'll give that a try tonight.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen.. see updated text above.

Comment: @ToDo.. I think that's the same as changing the "Download From" entry in "Software & Updates -> UbuntuSoftware", isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's the place.

Comment: @Ed it is possible that this mirror is not working, try to ping the mirror, if it is offline. switch to ubuntu's main repo

Comment: @Zeus77.. Yea, I've already tried a couple of servers, and I also verified that they are reachable both with ping and firefox.

Comment: @Ed can you paste the whole output in pastebin (or something similar) ?

Comment: @Zeus77... Ok, its here: http://www.umonfw.com/tmp/update_log

Comment: Note also that the log has all these "Unable to connect to mirror.cc.columbia.edu:http:" messages; but I am able to use Firefox to connect to that server.

Comment: @Ed. there seems to be a problem with this particular mirror and many people are having problems using apt within a proxy. how did you set your proxy? using only `http_proxy="http://username:password@proxyserver:port"` seems to work for some people. also try using apt without proxy if you can

Comment: @Zeus77.. Having the same problem with mirror.cc.vt.edu.  I set the proxy two ways: 1. in Network->NetworkProxy (apply system wide) and 2. setting the http_proxy variable in the Terminal environment.

Comment: Made some progress (I think)... added Acquire::http::proxy "http://<proxy>:<port>/"; to /etc/apt/apt.conf.  Now I get a "Forbidden" error instead of network access.

Comment: Perhaps you should set the **Download From** entry to **Other**. Then, in the **Choose a Download Server** dialog, you could select the **Select Best Server** button. This will take a few moments to complete, but you should get a fast server that *isn't* having problems

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my question, thanks to the comments posted...
The problem was that I am working behind a proxy, and while I had the **http_proxy** shell variable set and also had set the proxy in **Network->NetworkProxy**, apparently **apt** really wants to be told about this in the **/etc/apt/apt.conf** file.

After adding a line similar to this...

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://proxy_url_here:proxy_port/";
```

to /etc/apt.apt.conf, things worked much better.

Comment: Yes, it would be ideal if apt were able to work more automatically with a proxy, this is a common problem.